# Почему текст блока с абсолютным позиционированием внутри flex контейнера не растягивается на всю ширину?

Tags: css, flexbox, текст, position

Есть `flex` контейнер в котором блок `div` с текстом и абсолютным позиционированием.
Не могу понять почему текст в блочном элементе не растягивается на всю ширину, а занимает 2 строки..

Если убираю *абсолютное позиционирование* или ширину контейнеру увеличиваю до *230px*, то текст прекрасно умещается в 1 строку.

Но, как решить проблему не меняя размеры контейнера и сохраняя позиционирование у блока?

```css
.box-right {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 220px;
}

.code {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #225AAC;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.code div {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #225AAC;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-right">
  <form class="code">
    <div>I have a promocode</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;` или `width: fit-content;` ?

Comment: не работает, пришлось отказаться от `position: absolute;` позиционирование сбивает свойство ширины

Answer (score 0):

```
    .box-right {
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 220px;
  }
  
  .code {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #225AAC;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  
  .code div {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #225AAC;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: -110px; /*половина ширины блока */
  }
```